# How to return an 'await' variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, async-await, promise

I have the following JS code

```
async function readAtlasAll() {
  return await MongoClient.connect(url, async function(err, db) {
    var dbo = db.db("Users");
    c = dbo.collection("List");
    r = await c.find({}).toArray();
    console.log(r);
    return r;
  });
}

console.log(readAtlasAll());
```

I'm not sure why, but printing the result of readAtlasAll() comes before printing the variable r inside the function, even though I'm awaiting the result of r beforehand. The terminal prints `Promise { <pending> }` first and afterwards prints the contents of r.
I'm relatively new to JavaScript, so I would really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use both `await` and a plain callback on MongoDB API calls as the `await` won't do anything useful.  Use one or the other, not both.  This is because the MongoDB asynchronous APIs will return a promise if you do NOT pass a callback to them and you can then `await` that promise, but if you pass a callback, they do not return a promise, therefore the `await` does nothing useful at all.  Here's how you would implement it by leaving out the callback and using `await`:

```
async function readAtlasAll() {
    const db = await MongoClient.connect(url);
    const dbo = db.db("Users");
    const c = dbo.collection("List");
    const r = await c.find({}).toArray();
    return r;          // this will be the resolved value of the returned promise
}

readAtlasAll().then(r => {
   console.log(r);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Keep in mind that `await` has no magic powers at all.  ALL it does is suspend execution of the function until a promise resolves/rejects.  So, it only does anything useful when you `await` a promise.

And, further, ALL `async` functions return a promise so there is NO way to return an asynchronously-retrieved value directly from your function.  You have to use an asynchronous mechanism for communicating back an asynchronously retrieved value such as a promise, a callback or an event.  So `readAtlasAll()` can never return your value directly.

See [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for more info on that.

Comment: You can, it's just done differently.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK - I don't understand that comment.  Feel free to write your own answer if you have a better way to write this code or provide a specific suggestion for me to improve this answer.

Comment: Your answer works but the question was to return an awaited result as a variable in JavaScript and this can in fact be done with callbacks and/or either both, it's not hard to introduce at all if necessary for the development.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK - There is NO way in Javascript to return an asynchronously retrieved value directly from this `readAtlastAll()` function such that the OP's `console.log(readAtlasAll());` will show the result. If you think you have a way for `console.log(readAtlasAll());` to show the result, please write an answer and show us. Javascript simply doesn't work that way with asynchronous operations.  Yes, you could pass a callback into `readAtlastAll()`, but that's not returning the value from the function-that's the older mechanism for communicating asynchronous results which is in my answer.